# jQuery .data('key') for all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When using `.data('keyname')` on a jQuery set, I only seem to get the first value. I would like it to return an array of values from each element.

Is there a jQuery shortcut for pulling all values that does not involve iterating the set yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var dataValues = $(".yourElementSelector").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("keyname");
}).get();
```

This is about as short as it gets... `dataValues` will now be a nice array of your `data('keyname')` values.